# G-code G1 move command is not consistent with MM114 get motor position command

Tags: controller, stepper, g-code

I am using the G1 move command to rotate a a stepper motor with a Duet3D stepper controller board. I just realised by using the M114 command, which returns the actual motor position, that there is an error margin between the 2 commands, but I don't understand why as I directly ask a distance to move, which should be added to the relative motor position saved on the board.

1. **sending get position command:** M114
   returns: X:0.000
2. **sending move command:**
   M120 G91 G1 S1 X-28.897 F600 M121
3. **sending get position command after move is done:** M114

   returns: -28.934

Why is M114 returning a slightly higher value than what I asked the motor to move?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the minor correction of 0.5mm is because of auto calibration or homing. When the device is homed there is a minor correction applied for all the axis with respect to the end stops.

Another point I would check would be the step calculation for the motor. sometimes the mm/steps of motor calculation may not be perfect and has to be manually fine tuned. You can find the steps defined in the `config.g` file in the command `M92`. You can vary in steps of 0.005 for each axis and verify the movement.

The steps/mm latency is not visible in small machines but this latency increases with the size of machine.